# Jenkins fails with "PKIX path building" error

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab

Why does Jenkins fail with "PKIX path building failed" for SonarQube and GitLab plugins?

I found this article: 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message

However it didn't seem to answer the question fully.

Two pieces of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

and

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuring Jenkins to work with GitLab and SonarQube, the JVM needs to know the server's keystore and the certificate authorities (truststore) for which the external sites are signed with to establish an SSL connection.

On a CentOS server, in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins, add the following to the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS property:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to trustStore in JKS format> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password> -Djavax.ssl.keyStore=<path to server keystore in JKS format> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<password>"
```

The above is different from setting HTTPS in Jenkins, which can be setup using the following two properties:

```
JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE=<path to server keystore in JKS format>
JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=<password>
JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT=<port to listen on for https>
```

*Note: I kept coming back to this CloudBees article (https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message)  it's got the keyStore and trustStore backwards, and doesn't say to set both of them.*